# In Cypress sending form data using POST request is not working

Tags: cypress

New to Cypress and trying as proof of concept for company. I am facing a issue when through a POST request i am unable to test the React application. Following are the error messages received in Cypress electron app:

> Timed out retrying: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st
>   request to the route: 'formRequest'. No request ever occurred.

Following is the code snippet used in cypress `commands.js`:

```
    Cypress.Commands.add("form_request", (method, urlPathParam, formData) => {
  return cy
    .server()
    .route(method, "https://admin.teamapp.myhelpling.com" + urlPathParam)
    .as("formRequest")
    .window()
    .then(win => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open(method, "https://admin.teamapp.myhelpling.com" + urlPathParam);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("access-token", accesstoken);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("client", client);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("expiry", expiry);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("token-type", tokentype);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("uid", uid);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhr.send(formData);
    })
    .wait("@formRequest");
});
```

In the test spec file following is the code inside a Test case

```
cy.AppLogin();
let dataname = "Test FORMDATA API";
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("client[name]", dataname);
formData.append(
   "client[client_logo_attributes][content]",
   cy.fixture("/images/clients/Golden JPEG.jpeg")
);


cy.form_request("POST", "/admin/clients", formData).then(response => {
  cy.log(response.status);
});
```

Also, if i commenting the  `.wait("@formRequest");` from `commands.js` code above  following error is displayed:

> POST https://admin.teamapp.myhelpling.com/admin/clients 405 (Method
>   Not Allowed)

In the sources tab on dev tool I see a X(cross) mark on `xhr.send(formData)` line provided below:

```
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryAGOGnFVPveAa8gfv");
    xhr.send(formData);
  }); //.wait("@formRequest");
});
```

Secondly, can someone also help share some links how to debug the framework on my machine?

---

**Updates**

This application under test accept form data in the following format :

```
client[name] = "Cypress TER Client"
client[client_logo_attributes][content] = Some_Blob
```

With `cy.Request()` I assume I had to convert that into JSON as body of the request. This is the following transformation of FormData into JSON:

```
body: {
      client: {
        name: "Cypress TER Client",
        client_logo_attributes: {
          content: "fx:../images/clients/Bull Client.jpg"
        }
      }
```

I believe I'm not doing that correctly. Please suggest.

I checked how POSTMAN sends this request out and tried that too but no luck. Here's the code I tried:

```
body: qs.stringify({
      mode: "formdata",
      formdata: [
        {
          key: "client[name]",
          value: "Cypress TER Client",
          type: "text"
        },
        {
          key: "client[client_logo_attributes][content]",
          type: "file",
          src: cy.readFile("cypress//fixtures//images/clients//Bull Client.jpg")
        }
      ]
    })
```

---

Thanks Eric. Based on your feedback below I amended the existing code to look like following:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("formrequest", (method, url, formData, done) => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(method, url);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("access-token", accesstoken);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("client", client);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("expiry", expiry);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("token-type", tokentype);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("uid", uid);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.send(formData);
  xhr.onload = function() {
    done(xhr);
  };
  xhr.onerror = function() {
    done(xhr);
  };
});
```

Calling code looks like this now:

```
it.only("Test", () => {
    cy.AppLogin();

    let blobObj = cy.create_blob(
      "/images/clients/Bull Client.jpg",
      "image/jpg"
    );

    dataname = "Test FORMDATA API";
    formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("client[name]", dataname);
    formData.append("client[client_logo_attributes][content]", blobObj);

    let url = "https://admin.teamapp.myhelpling.com/admin/clients";

    let method = "POST";

    cy.formrequest(method, url, formData, function(response) {
      expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
    });
  });
```

No luck.

This application under test accept form data in the following format :

```
client[name] = "Cypress TER Client"
client[client_logo_attributes][content] = Some_Blob
```

This is the following transformation of `FormData` into JSON:

```
body: {
      client: {
        name: "Cypress TER Client",
        client_logo_attributes: {
          content: "fx:../images/clients/Bull Client.jpg"
        }
      }
```

I believe I'm not doing that correctly. Please suggest.

I checked how POSTMAN sends this request out and tried that too but no luck. Here's the code I tried:

```js
body: qs.stringify({
      mode: "formdata",
      formdata: [
        {
          key: "client[name]",
          value: "Cypress TER Client",
          type: "text"
        },
        {
          key: "client[client_logo_attributes][content]",
          type: "file",
          src: cy.readFile("cypress//fixtures//images/clients//Bull Client.jpg")
        }
      ]
    })
```

Comment: The details appear to be incomplete - please show how `accesstoken`, `client`, `expiry`, `tokentype`, `uid` get into the custom command. Are they constants defined  in **./support/index.js**?

Comment: accesstoken, client, expiry, tokentype, uid are fetched from LOGIN Post command and then set in variables declared inside commands.js.

Comment: That makes sense. I wonder if the problem is related to this note in the docs [cy.route() cannot be debugged using cy.request()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#cy-route-cannot-be-debugged-using). It has been mentioned in other questions that you can't use `cy.route` with XHR originating from the test itself, only from the application under test.

Comment: @eric99 - Do you think there is a workaround for this?

Comment: Indeed, sorry for forgetting about this. @nickbing found a third party repo that might be useful - [cypress-auto-stub-example](https://github.com/PinkyJie/cypress-auto-stub-example). Perhaps this code will catch XHR originating from the test (as opposed to the app under test).  For reference, Nick's question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54766816/cypress-request-wait-by-default/54776582#54776582).

Comment: The other idea I was going to suggest was to use `xhr.onload()` after the `xhr.send()`, but I was stuck on how to pass the promise back from the command. Perhaps you need a callback function to be passed in to the command (after `formData`), and this callback will invoke `done()` in the normal way for async tests.

Comment: Maybe, just pass `done` in as a parameter, then add `xhr.onload = () => done();` after `xhr.send()`. That removes the need for the Cypress `cy.wait()`, which needs a bit of an overhaul IMO.

Comment: no luck...made suggested changes and logged a new issue at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54939625/multipart-formdata-post-request-just-doesnt-work-in-cypress-for-me