# Cypress request wait by default?

Tags: javascript, angular, automation, e2e-testing, cypress

I need Cypress to wait for any xhr requests to complete by default before performing any operations. Is there any way to make this as a default or any other alternatives because the application I am testing is slow and makes a lot of api calls?

Edit: By writing a single statement for every api request is getting messy and unnecessary work. Need a way to make this easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found something that works for me here https://github.com/PinkyJie/cypress-auto-stub-example

Look for cy.waitUntilAllAPIFinished

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to wait for a specific xhr you can do it making use of `cy.route()`. I use this in some scenarios and it is really useful. The general steps to use it are:

- `cy.server()`
- `cy.route('GET','**/api/my-call/**').as('myXHR');`
- Do things in the UI such as clicking on a button that will trigger such api calls
- `cy.wait(@myXHR)`

This way if such call isn't triggered your test will fail. You can find extensive documentation about this [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/server.html#Syntax)

Comment: I don't want to wait for a specific call. I need a way to wait for all the xhr requests by default, writing a wait statement for every call is getting too messy and a lot of work.

Comment: the problem here is if you need to wait for 45 api calls. How to do this in an easy way?

Answer (score 0):

I partialy solve the problem adding a **waitAll** command and ovewrite **route** command in **support** folder:

```
const routeCallArr = [];
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('route', (route, ...params) => {
    const localRoute = route(...params);
    if (localRoute.alias === undefined) return; 
    localRoute.onRequest = function() {
        routeCallArr.push({alias: `@${localRoute.alias}`, starTime: Date.now()});
    }
    localRoute.onResponse = function() {
        clearCall(`@${localRoute.alias}`);
    }
})
const waitAll = (timeOut = 50000, options = {verbose: false, waitNested: false}) => {
    const filterRouteCallArr = [];
    const date = Date.now();
    for (const routeCall of routeCallArr) {
        if ((date - routeCall.starTime) > timeOut) continue;
        filterRouteCallArr.push(routeCall.alias);
    }
    if (options.verbose ){
        console.table(routeCallArr.map(routeCall => ({
            deltaTime: date - routeCall.starTime,
            alias: routeCall.alias,
            starTime: routeCall.starTime,
        })));
        console.log(routeCallArr, filterRouteCallArr)
    };
    routeCallArr.length = [];
    if (filterRouteCallArr.length > 0) {
        const waiter = cy.wait(filterRouteCallArr, {timeout: timeOut});
        options.waitNested && waiter.then(() => {
            if (routeCallArr.length > 0) {
                waitAll(timeOut, options);
            }
        });
    }
}
Cypress.Commands.add('waitAll', waitAll)
```

And in the test instead of use `cy.wait(['@call01',..., '@callN']);` I use `cy.waitAll();`

The problem with this implementation came when have nested calls in a relative separate time interval from original calls. In that case you can use a recursive wait `cy.waitAll(50000, {waitNested: true});`